# Flutter: How to remove underling from text when I'm typing into text field?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout

I want to remove this underline.

[image: See This image]

This is my input field

```dart
TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
            hintText: label,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            filled: true,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              borderSide:
                  const BorderSide(color: AppColors.textGrey2, width: 0.5),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              borderSide:
                  const BorderSide(color: AppColors.textGrey2, width: 0.5),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide:
                    const BorderSide(color: AppColors.textGrey2, width: 0.5)),
          ),
          obscureText: obscureText,
        ),
```

I need this output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the styling from the text, add this line to your `TextField`

```
  style: TextStyle(decoration:TextDecoration.none),
```

Comment: thanks ... it's working but not exactly what I want.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want then? as far as I understood from your question, the above code removes the underlines from the hint text. Please explain more your specific need

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the underline in the hint text of your `TextField`?
If you put a Material widget above in your widget tree this should go by default.
Otherwise you can set it in the `TextStyle` of your `hintText`
`hintStyle: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none)`

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late but u can try this

`decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none)`